# How to set up a onClick test for the following:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am new to unit testing and would like to know how could I set up a test for the following onClick

I have done some onClicks before but how could I call the following event and get it passing on my test:

file.js

```
return (
 <DropdownItem key={action.RouteId} 
 id={action.RouteName}
 onClick={() => {
   if(this.props.action && (this.props.action.routeId !== action.RouteId)){
       this.props.setTarget(null);
       this.props.setAction(action);
    }
   }}>
```

Usually, this is how I set up my onClick tests: How could I get the test above to work based on this:

test.file.js

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  wrapper = mount(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Component {...baseProps} />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
});

it(' should call button click event', () => {
  baseProps.onClick.mockClear();
  wrapper.setProps({});
  wrapper.find('COMPONENT').setState({});
  wrapper.update();
  wrapper.find('#id').simulate('click');
  expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Comment: One way would be to spyOn the onClick handler. Another might be to spy on setTarget() and/or setAction(), dispatch the click and see if they fire. Lots of examples available online for this.

Comment: Is it possible to do without spyOn - not familiar with it